# how to disable page responsiveness for IE in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to remove the page responsiveness in Bootstrap 3 but only for versions of Internet Explorer. I have reviewed the documentation to [remove page responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) overall, but can it be device or browser specific?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty javascript solution for IE8 and 9: (assumes grid size ~980)

```
if ( ( (/msie 8./i).test(navigator.appVersion) || (/msie 9./i).test(navigator.appVersion) ) {
  var body = document.querySelector('body');

  body.style.minWidth = '980px';
}
```

You could also accomplish this with CSS if you're setting classes on the `<html>` tags in IE conditionals.

Assuming `<html class="ie8">` for example,

```
html.ie8 {
 min-width : 980px;
}
html.ie8 body {
 min-width : 980px;
}
```

An even more thorough way would be to override the @media calls with your own, targeting the ie html class again, and use css load hierarchy or the odd `!important` tag to get it done.